# Remote Site Setting in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Can we add a list of domain like this :
www.google.*

into Remote Site Setting.
Google has a lot of domain :

```
google.com.ar
google.com.au
google.ca
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008z6PIAQ) for an old question that was left unanswered.

Remote Site Settings are only for HTTP calls you make from Salesforce out to another server, so if you know your contained list for outbound calls you shouldn't have to worry about new ones dynamically being needed. If you want a faster way to update this, take a look at the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/), which should let you bulk change the values through underlying XML (with the caveat that you need at least one Remote Site defined in the org first).